# <asp:Button CommandArgument=<%: variable %> does not work -" variable" not populating with "value"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to pass a variable into my "asp:Button CommandArgument" - I know that I've got to jump through some hoops as runat=server is set, but I have tried everything I have found so far, but to no avail

I know that my code behind works nicely as, if I explicitly define the variables in my "asp:Button CommandArgument" everything works - but as soon as I try to insert a variable via <% %> syntax?  The variable is NOT replaced by the string it represents

I'm using vStudio 2019 community preview (and 2017) as my IDE, targeting .net framework 4.7.2 - everything builds cleanly, and I know that the value for the variable is being set - it's jut not making it into my "asp:Button CommandArgument" and I need it to

I've tried everything I have found - all permutations of the <% $> syntax I can find, tried using CodeExpressionBuilder

The pertinent part of my problematic code is

```
<% if (variable is "value") { %>

<asp:Button ID = "button1" 
    runat = "server" 
    Text = "Processing '<%: variable %>' Records" 
    CommandArgument = '<%: variable %>' 
    OnCommand = "button1_Click" 
/>

<% } %>
```

I expect the variable I am inserting into the "asp:Button CommandArgument" to be replaced by it's current value

What I get? Various error messages and the literal translation of my ' or " wrapped <%: <%# <%= variable %> which doesn't help

I know I can hard-code some of what I want to accomplish - but that's not optimal, and doesn't help me when I want to pass variable dates to my procedures via "asp:Button CommandArgument"

I know I must be doing something wrong - but cannot, for the life of me, figure out what

Any suggestions?

Comment: I noticed that the `CommandArgument` part is using single quotes around what would be the value.  Should those be double quotes like the other attributes?  Does the `Text` attribute get the correct value?  And where/how is "variable" defined?  Perhaps it's a scope issue?

Comment: Use a Repeater Control to add controls and use DataBinding Expressions to dynamically add the text to the conrol.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET will not allow you to declare controls like this:

```
<asp:Button ID = "button1" 
    runat = "server" 
    Text = "Processing '<%: variable %>' Records" 
    CommandArgument = '<%: variable %>' 
    OnCommand = "button1_Click" 
/>
```

The reason is that `<asp:Button … />` is pre-processed by the interpreter before any inline statements (eg. `<%: variable %>`).

To set/modify properties of an ASP.NET form control, you have to change them in code-behind.  The most popular place would be in the `Page_Load()` event.  Like this:

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!Page.IsPostBack)
   {
       button1.Text = "Processing " + variable + " Records"; 
       button1.CommandArgument = variable;
   }
}
```